# Javascript/jQuery object coding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a newly created Javascript object called EditableObject in my custom .js file

```
function EditableObject(e, dv, i) {
this.element = e;
this.default_value = dv;
this.set = 0;
this.id = i;

alert(this.element.html());

this.element.click(function (event) {
    alert(this.element.html());
});
```

}

In my main page, I have a div called "field" that has the text "yeah" in it like such:

```
 <div id="field">yeah</div>
```

In the script portion of my main page, I've got:

```
var t = new EditableObject($("#field"), "value", 1);
```

When the page loads, there is an alert box that says "yeah". But when I click on the div, I get an error saying that "this.element is undefined". Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `click` handler, `this` refers to a different scope (depending on browser, it'll be the `event` object or the current function). You need a closure to access parent scope's `this`:

```
var self = this;
this.element.click(function (event) {
    alert(self.element.html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing with `this` is that it differs in each function depending on the context. In jQuery bind functions, it is the element itself so the most straight-forward solution is:

```
this.element.click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).html());
    // this is element, $(this) is jQuery object containing element
});
```

So currently, `this` refers to the element, which differs from e.g. the line

```
this.id = i;
```

where it refers to the instance of `EditableObject`, because there you use `this` in a different function.

Answer (score 0):

*this* inside of your click handler refers to the DOM object, not the instance of `EditableObject`.

You could modify it like this:

```
this.element.click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The *this* in your click function refers only to the click itself. I believe you can use

```
e.html();
```

there instead